# Error with float multiplication and display in GUI

Tags: java, jframe

I am working on a school project where a pricelist is read from a file, stored in a database as an object, then a shopping list is read, total calculated, and displayed in a GUI, but the display is not coming up correctly, Im getting all zeros for the cost of each item, I have attached the code as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Project1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the filename of your shopping list:"); //Prompt user to enter filename

    Database base = new Database(); //Create Database
    File file = new File(input);    //Create File object
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file); //Create Scanner object
    float total = 0;                //float to hold sum of grocery list
    String list = "";               //String to create receipt
    float a = 0;                    //float to hold total of each individual item

    /*This while loop will run as long as the File object has a next line. It will tokenize the line from 
     * the file, append to the string the number, and name, create a running total for the grocery list, 
     * and append the string with the cost per item.
     */
    StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    while(in.hasNextLine()){

        input = in.nextLine();                                      //Read the next line from the file
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, ",");                //Create Tokenizer object with line from file
        input = tokenizer.nextToken();                              //Get first token (Object number)
        list += (input + "  " + base.getName(input) + " ");
        input = tokenizer.nextToken();
        a = Float.parseFloat(input);
        total += a;
        a = a * (base.getPrice(input));
        list += ("$" + a + "\n");
    }
    in.close();

    JFrameBuild frame = new JFrameBuild(list, total);

}
}
```

Next Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * The Database class will process a .txt file to tokenize the contents and assemble an array of objects.
 * @author Andrew
 *
 */

public class Database {
ProduceItem[] array = new ProduceItem[16];  //Create String array

public Database() throws FileNotFoundException{
    String name = "PriceList.txt";
    File file = new File(name); //Create file object
    int i = 0;


    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);  //Create Scanner object to read from file
    String line = null; //String for input

    while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){                                     //While loop to sort through the file
            array[i] = new ProduceItem();                               //Initalize object
            line = inputFile.nextLine();                                //Read line from file
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ","); //Tokenize the line
            array[i].setCode(tokenizer.nextToken());                    //Set the ID code for the object
            array[i].setName(tokenizer.nextToken());                    //Set the name for the object
            array[i].setPrice(Float.parseFloat(tokenizer.nextToken())); //Set the price for the object
            i++;                                                        //increment the counter
    }   
    inputFile.close();
}
/**
 * This method will sort the array of objects and return the name of the ProduceItem with the matching 
 * ID code.
 * 
 * @param code The code of the ProduceItem we need the name of
 * @return  Returns the name of the ProduceItem
 */
public String getName(String code){
    String name = "";                                                   //Initalize the name String

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){                              //For loop to sort the array
        if(code.equals(array[i].getCode())){
            name = array[i].getName();
            break;                                                      //Break the loop
        }
    }
    return name;
}
/**
 * This method sorts the array and returns the price of the object.
 * 
 * @param code The code of the object we need to price
 * @return Returns the price of the said object per pound
 */
public float getPrice(String code){
    float price = 0F;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(code.equals(array[i].getName())){
            price = array[i].getPrice();
            break;
        }
    }
    return price;


}

}
```

Next Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class JFrameBuild {

public JFrameBuild(String line, float total){
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shopping Receipt");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize( 300,300);//width, height);
    frame.setLocation(200,100);//x, y);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(25, 25);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Shopping total is:  $" + total);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    textArea.setText(line);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);



}

}
```

Next Class:

/**
 * The ProduceItem class creates produce objects and their corresponding data.
 * @author Andrew
 *
 */
    public class ProduceItem {

```
private String code;
private String name;
private float price;
/**
 * Standard constructor for the ProduceItem class
 * @param code  Code of the ProduceItem object
 * @param name  Name of the ProduceItem object
 * @param price Price of the ProduceItem object
 */
public ProduceItem(String code, String name, float price){
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;

}
/**
 * NO Arg constructor for the ProduceItem class
 */
public ProduceItem(){
    //No Arg constructor
}
/**
 * Accessor method for code variable
 * @return the code for the item
 */
public String getCode(){
    return code;
}
/**
 * Accessor method for the name variable
 * @return  the name for the item
 */
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
/**
 * Accessor method for the price variable
 * @return the price of the item
 */
public float getPrice(){
    return price;
}
/**
 * Mutator method for the code variable
 * @param code The code for the item
 */
public void setCode(String code){
    this.code = code;
}
/**
 * Mutator method for the name variable
 * @param name The name of the item
 */
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
/**
 * Mutator method for the price variable
 * @param price The price of the item
 */
public void setPrice(float price){
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

And the following are the txt datas:
Price List:

```
4019,APPLES,0.99
4218,APRICOTS,3.49
4771,AVOCADOS,2.59
4011,BANANAS,.69
4045,CHERRIES,4.99
4263,DATES,3.99
4027,GRAPEFRUIT,1.09
4637,GRAPES,2.76
4053,LEMONS,3.45
4319,MELON,1.99
4377,NECTARINE,3.69
4012,ORANGES,2.49
4037,PEACHES,2.99
4026,PEARS,1.99
4029,PINEAPPLE,2.59
4041,PLUMS,3.49
```

ShoppingList:

```
4012,4.03
4019,2.3
4011,1.72
4029,1.7
4027,2.37
4037,2.99
4637,2.01
4053,0.56
4319,5.65
4026,0.99
4041,0.49
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way you are splitting your line, you are actually passing in the "quantity" value into your `getPrice` method

```
input = in.nextLine();                                      //Read the next line from the file
tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, ",");                //Create Tokenizer object with line from file
input = tokenizer.nextToken();                              //Get first token (Object number)
list += (input + "  " + base.getName(input) + " ");
// And input is now the "quanity", not the code...
input = tokenizer.nextToken();
a = Float.parseFloat(input);
total += a;
a = a * (base.getPrice(input));
list += ("$" + a + "\n");
```

Then in your `getPrice` method, you are comparing the "code" with the product's name...

```
if (code.equals(array[i].getName())) {
```

which will never be `true`.  Instead you should be using `getCode`

```
if (code.equals(array[i].getCode())) {
```

I've already used `String#split` over `StringTokenizer` for simplicity (among other reason), you should also avoid `String` concatenation within loops, where you can. In your case, it's not a "massive" deal, but you should practice good habits when ever you can.

Instead, you should be using a `StringBuilder`, for example...

```
StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder(64);
while (in.hasNextLine()) {

    input = in.nextLine();                                      //Read the next line from the file
    String[] tokens = input.split(",");
    String code = tokens[0];
    String quanity = tokens[1];
    list.append(code).append("  ").append(base.getName(code)).append(" ");
    a = Float.parseFloat(quanity);
    total += a;
    a = a * (base.getPrice(code));
    list.append("$").append(a).append("\n");
}
in.close();

JFrameBuild frame = new JFrameBuild(list.toString(), total);
```

It's faster and less memory intensive.

It'd also have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to better handle your resources, as it will ensure that your resources are closed properly if a error occurs or not

Comment: I did as you suggested in regards the the get price method, but Im still not getting proper results on the receipt GUI.

Comment: Define "propert" result